# IntelliJ formatting HTML

Tags: html, intellij-idea, formatting

I was not able to find a way to make IntelliJ format HTML code consistently through inserting new lines and indents.For example, this code:

```
<li class="nav"><a href="/about">
About</a></li>
```

Should be formatted to this:

```
<li class="nav">
    <a href="/about">About</a>
</li>
```

Or:

```
<li class="nav">
    <a href="/about">
        About
    </a>
</li>
```

When I try to re-format selected text or entire file, this segment is not changed!!!

I have already tried to play with **Preferences > Language > HTML > Code Style**, but no success!

Answer (score 3):

This is related to *Element inlining*. When you look at the code style settings for HTML there is *Inline elements* selection. When you remove `a` tag from this selection and reformat your code, the code will be arranged the way you want it (i.e. `a` will not be kept on the same line as `li`).

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you for your very elaborated answer, removing the a-tag from this list does in fact do the trick and I get my 2rd option as above, but, ideally, I wanted to get my 1) option. So, I have looked at the 'inline elements' list several times looking for the li-tag and not the a-tag. So, I still do not understand why indenting was not applied to li-tag, because it is not in this list?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate again to navigate to **Preferences > Language > HTML > Code Style** and configure as:

[image]
[image]

Then try to select the code and reformat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but honestly, I do not see from the above what I need to change? Ideally, I like to get my first option as above and not the second option, thanks